# How do i progressively load the google line chart from a MySql databse so as to give it an animating effect?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, charts, google-visualization

**Here is my code:**

```
<?php
/* Your Database Name */

$DB_NAME = 'temp_database';

/* Database Host */
$DB_HOST = 'localhost';

/* Your Database User Name and Password */
$DB_USER = 'root';
$DB_PASS = '';





  /* Establish the database connection */
  $mysqli = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);

  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
  }


  $dateFrom=isset($_GET['datepickerFrom']) ? $_GET['datepickerFrom'] : '';
  $dateTo=isset($_GET['datepickerTo']) ? $_GET['datepickerTo'] : '';
  if($dateFrom && $dateTo !=NULL)
    {
      $dateFrom = new DateTime($dateFrom);
      $dateTo = new DateTime($dateTo);
        $dateFrom = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $dateFrom->format('Y-m-d'));
        $dateTo = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $dateTo->format('Y-m-d'));
    }





  if($dateFrom && $dateTo !=NULL)
  {
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT datetime,temperature FROM tempLog where datetime between '$dateFrom%' and '$dateTo%' order by datetime ASC");  //"2018-03-15" AND "2018-03-26"  

    //print_r($result);
  }
  else
   {
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT datetime,temperature FROM tempLog order by DateTime");  
   } 


  echo "$dateFrom<br/>";
  echo "$dateTo<br/>";




  $rows = array();
  $table = array();
  $table['cols'] = array(

    array('label' => 'Date-Time', 'type' => 'string'),
    array('label' => 'Temperature', 'type' => 'number')

);
    /* Extract the information from $result */
    foreach($result as $r) {

      $temp = array();

      // The following line will be used to slice the Pie chart

      $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['datetime']); 

      // Values of the each slice

      $temp[] = array('v' => (float) $r['temperature']); 
      $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
    }

$table['rows'] = $rows;

// convert data into JSON format
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);
//echo $jsonTable;

//header("Refresh: 50");   //Put the seconds after which the page needs to be refreshed

?>


<html>
  <head>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    /*$(window).on("throttledresize", function (event) {
    drawChart();
});*/

    function drawChart() {

      // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$jsonTable?>);
      var options = {
                      title: 'Temperature Record updated every 5 seconds',
                      //is3D: 'true',
                      curveType: 'function',

                      width: "100%",
                      height: 500,
                      //legend: 'top',
                      axisTitlesPosition: 'out',
                       'isStacked': true,
                       colors: ['#0598d8', '#f97263'],
                       chartArea: {
                           left: "15%",
                           top: "5%",
                           bottom:"40%",
                           height: "100%",
                           width: "100%"
                       },
  vAxis:{
    title:'Temperature'
  },
  hAxis: { 
    title:'Date',
    minValue: 0,
     maxValue: 50 },
  //curveType: 'function',
  pointSize: 3,
  dataOpacity: 0.6,
  animation: {
                duration: 500,
                startup: true, //This is the new option
                easing:'out'
            }

        };
      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      // Do not forget to check your div ID
      //var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
      //chart.draw(data, options);

          var i=data.getNumberOfRows();
      //alert(i);
      function resize() {
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));


    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
  window.onload = resize();
  window.onresize = resize;

}



    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        width:100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin:5% auto auto auto;
        //background:#e6e6e6;
    }
</style>

</head>

  <body>

    <!--<center><h1>Temperature Graph</h1></center>-->


    <div style="display:block;
    zoom: 1;
    text-align: center;">
        <form id="dateselect" action="date.php" method="GET">
              <div style="display: inline-block; margin:5px;">From: <input type="text" name ="datepickerFrom" id="datepickerFrom" style=""></div>

              <div style="display: inline-block; margin: 5px;">To: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="datepickerTo" id="datepickerTo"></div><br>
              <div style="display: inline-block;"><input type="submit" value="Submit"  /></div>&nbsp;
              <div style="display: inline-block;"><button type="button" onClick="window.location.reload();">Refresh</button></div>
        </form>  
    </div>    
    <div class = "container" id="chart_div"></div>  <!--Load bootstrap container for responsiveness-->

<script>
    $( function() {
     $( "#datepickerFrom,#datepickerTo" ).datepicker( {
    //showButtonPanel: true,
    changeMonth:true,
    changeYear:true

    });
  } );

  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Problem:**

I am able to fetch the data and populate my chart. But what i need is the line chart should be populated incrementally so as to give it a loading type effect.

Using **"animate"** on startup in options **just pulls a "Line" from below the page every time the page is loaded**. I don't want that. I want it to animate it such that it progressively fills my chart.

I saw several posts on stackoverflow where people needed loading like effect and they eventually got it working by just **putting NULL values in the chart initially** and then loading the data. But in my case those values are **not hardcoded** and i am fetching *them as JSON from my DB*. I am not able to figure out how to load null data initially on every page refresh/load and then load the original DB fetched values.

if anyone could solve this it'd be of great help. Thanks :)

**EDIT:**

I want it something like this http://jsfiddle.net/HDu8H/ from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16857382/9578024) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39797489/9578024) But those can be easily done for hardcoded data values.. i need them to be drawn using dynamic values fetched from my database.

Comment: Just apply whats in the jsfiddle with your code it should work fine, yours is *hardcoded* too once it hits the browser from your server (your not using ajax).. if you have a large number of data points then look into initialising the `nulled` instance then load in the data with ajax or server-sent-events.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @LawrenceCherone :) I have already tried to use the code from the above jsfiddle link but somewhere something is going wrong in the process.. i am a newbie in web development and not able to figure out where i am going wrong. Can you please explain in a little more detail? That'd be of great help.. Thanks!